# Renaming the argument name in JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I created a web service using JAX-WS in RSA 7.5 and Websphere 7 using bottom-up approach. When I open the WSDL in SOAP UI, then the arguments section is appearing like this:

```
<!--Optional-->
<arg0>
    <empID>?</empId>
</arg0>
<!--Optional-->
<arg1>
    <empName>?</empName>
</arg1>
<!--Optional-->
<arg2>
    <empAddress>?</empAddress>
</arg2>
<!--Optional-->
<arg3>
    <empCountry>?</empCountry>
</arg3>
```

The service method takes the above 4 elements as the parameters to return the employee details.

1) I want to rename this arg0, arg1, and so on with some valid names.

2) I want to remove the `<!--optional-->` present above the arg tags. (For removing the `<!--optional-->` from elements name, I used @XMLElement(required=true)). But I am not sure where exactly to use this annotation in this case :(

Please help.

Regards,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You put the `@XMLElement(required=true)` above the variables in your class that are being returned from your service. I just learned about that option about a month ago. So right above where you declare empName put the tag and required.

To rename the parameters of your service use the `@WebParam(name="<name you want in soap>")` in front of each input variable to the service.

For example, if you have a service method called `get(String name)` it would look something like `get(@WebParam(name = "name") String name)`

---

You are correct, now that I read your comment again. The services I support use Objects in the input and output, which is why I put the XMLElement tag in the class of those objects.

You need to put the tag in the class that declares your variables that are passed in or returned to the service. If those happen to be declared in your service class that is fine. The main point is that you put that XMLElement tag above the variable declaration, versus putting it on a getter or setter.

This tutorial shows some examples of the usage. [JAXB tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: IF i put the `@XMLElement(required=true)` above the EmpName member variable, then will it remove the `<1--Optional-->` present above the <arg0> tag? I think it wont work, i have to place this somewhere in the service class itself since the arg0 is passed in the service itself. Have you tried this out? I don't have the DEV system available nw, else i might have given nit a try.But I think doing this will remove the `<!--Optional-->` from the empName but not from above the `<arg0>`

Comment: You have to put the required=true tag above each variable in your data, so all 4 in your case. I do support services and it always annoyed me in SoapUI too because we have those tags on all of our variables. I just found out a month ago about using the XMLElement tag would remove optional tags from what SoapUi generates.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I tried your suggestions and most of them worked :) Can you tell me a couple of things: 1) when i run the url present in the WSDL for checking whether the service is up or not, then i get a message: `Hello! This is an Axis2 Web Service!` My question is why it shows Axis2? Does JAX-WS have got any relation with Axis2? 2) Today I implemented SOAPHandler for my web service. I used the annotation `@handlerchain(file="filepath")` and the file was placed in WebContent folder. It threw me an exception. But placing it under the service package worked fine. Why?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without knowing your system. I work with JBoss, and in order to use Axis, you have to deploy the Axis.jar file in jboss. Your server may have Axis2 jar files deployed. Axis is almost like it's own container for managing web services deployed in it. So you first deploy "Axis", then within Axis, you deploy Axis built web services. As far as the handlerchain, it's very common to have classpath issues with programs when referencing internal files. I'm not as sure about that one, but I think it's something to do with the classpath.

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is some way to implement the SOAPHandler without using annotations in JAX-WS ? I dont want to use any annotation because of some problems related to Websphere 7. Please let me know.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Websphere, but it looks like you would use a web.xml file to set the values instead of annotations. Annotations are a replacement for the xml configuration files usually. There are things you can set in xml files that do not have annotation equivalents yet. Look at this link to see how maybe. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaag%2Fcache%2Fpubwascacheappawebxml.htm