# Different tag names when using SOAPUI between WSDL in Wildfly and Websphere

Tags: tags, websphere, wildfly

I have two Application server running: Wildfly and Websphere.
Using Wildfly and checking the WSDL with SOAPUI, I get the following output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://xxx/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:Login>
         <username>xxx</username>
         <password>xxx</password>
         <accessArea>xxx</accessArea>
         <extendName>xxx</extendName>
      </web:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But if I use the same war file in Websphere, I always get this result:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="xxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:login>
         <arg0>xxx</arg0>
         <arg1>xxx</arg1>
         <arg2>xxx</arg2>
         <arg3>xxx</arg3>
      </web:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Does someone has an idea why all the tagnames are arg0, arg1, ..., when do the same thing in Websphere and checking it with SOAPUI?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this intended to be "top-down" with the WSDL included in the app?  Or "bottom-up" generated from Java?    If the latter, what does the Java interface looks like (show us the annotations)?

Comment: Not sure why the difference, but the jax-ws spec jsr224 sec 3.6.1 says the "arg(n)" names are the default.    Wildfly may have some way of customizing things that WAS is not aware of, I'm speculating.

Comment: Ok, well, something that I maybe can work with. Would it be like: it is as it is, I do not really know what to do but now I can rely on the specs and maybe find a solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: I went through the code and I found out that it should be bottom - up.

Comment: With your help I found something where someone else had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444138/renaming-the-argument-name-in-jax-ws - my Java source code:     @WebMethod(operationName = "Login")    @WebResult(name = "LoginReturn") /* creates the <LoginReturn>-tag */
    public String login(
            @WebParam(name = "username") String username,
            @WebParam(name = "password") String password,
            @WebParam(name = "accessArea") String accessArea,
            @WebParam(name = "extendName") String extendName) throws RemoteException;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a long time I was able to solve the problem.
There are a lot of differences between Wildfly and Websphere, and one of them seems to be related to annotations.
For having XMLElements to be recognized, you have to annotate them in the respective method for Websphere, too.

```
public someMethod( @WebParam(name="xyz" ... )
```

Whereas, Wildfly is able to dissolve them by itself.

Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have taken the project over from someone else, so I am not really into this topic. I found nothing that hints to top-down or bottom-up.